# How does android's repo tool knows which branch to use for each repo?

Tags: android, git, android-source, repo

Google's repo tool is used to clone all the android repositories to the right places. It reads the repositories from a .xml file like this one: https://github.com/GrapheneOS/platform_manifest/blob/11/default.xml

However, how does repo know in which branch to put each repository it clones? There's no commit/branch information on the .xml

For example, it just says

```
  <project path="device/google/bonito-sepolicy" name="device_google_bonito-sepolicy" groups="device,bonito" remote="grapheneos" />
```

for this repository. Some repositories (like this one) have only one branch, but some (mostly from google) have lots of branches. And not all of them are updates on `master`.

So, how it works?

Answer (score 1):

A manifest(excluding the ones in `.repo/local_manifests`), which is `default.xml` in your case, has a `default` element.

```
<default revision="refs/tags/android-11.0.0_r27"
           remote="aosp"
           sync-j="4" />
```

If a `project` element does not have its own `revision` or `upstream`, the one in the `default` element, `revision="refs/tags/android-11.0.0_r27"`,  is used. It's the same for other attributes. The `project` does not have its own `remote` and `sync-j` either, so the ones in `default` are used.

For more details, you could read the document under `.repo/repo/docs`.